# Error executing DDL "alter table add constraint foreign key () references (id)" via JDBC Statement

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-many, many-to-one

Error executing DDL "alter table  child add constraint  foreign key (parent_id) references  (id)" via JDBC Statement  caused by  Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint '' in the referenced table ''

caused by
Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint '' in the referenced table ''

Below are my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Child> child = new HashSet<>();
```

Below is another entity class for manytoOneampping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("child")
    private Parent parent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in db, duplicates tables were being created so that's why i was getting that error

Adding below annotation solved my problem :

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is changing the foreign_key name to match the primary key name of the other entity class.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private BigInteger id;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = AppUser.class)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "id")
private AppUser user;
```

The name in `@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "id"`) is what was causing the error in my case.